# Type safe enum pattern implementation with generics

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, enums, type-safety

How could the typesafe enum pattern be implemented on a generic class? Let's assume it's implemented along these lines

```
public class KnownSetting<T>
{
    public readonly static KnownSetting<String> Name = new KnownSetting<String>("name", "Default Name", t => t);
    public readonly static KnownSetting<int> Size = new KnownSetting<String>("size", "25", t => Converter.ToInt32);

    public String Key { get; set; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public Func<String, T> Converter { get; set; }

    private KnownSetting(String key, T defaultValue, Func<String, T> converter)
    {
        Key = key;
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        Converter = converter;
    }
}
```

The implementation of the pattern is correct this way since the constructor remains private, but when using this construct, it looks wrong:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void main()
    {
        var x = KnownSetting<?>.Name;
    }
}
```

Then an option would be to split it in two, KnownSetting container class and the Setting implementation, but then the scope of the constructor cannot be private so as to be instantiated from within the container.

How can this pattern be implemented so that the generics aspect of it stays concealed from the end-user, but remains strongly typed? Is there a more suitable pattern, or is there a better way to implement it?

**Update**
I added a second sample to illustrate that I do want the type of the setting to be generic.

Comment: Your static field has a separate value for each `T`.  You don't want that.

Comment: The best I can think is make the constructor internal and go with your "container class" idea, then you only have to rely on programmers' discipline within the same assembly.

Comment: @SLaks Why wouldn't I want that?

Comment: @default.kramer Of course you are right that relying on discipline would work, but if I could prevent any error by spending a bit more time on design, it's worth it.

Comment: @Spooles You wouldn't want that unless `KnownSetting<int>.Name != KnownSetting<String>.Name` is OK with you.

Comment: @mikez You are right, of course I don't want that. It is the point of my request.

Comment: @Spooles: That's what I was saying.

Comment: I suppose You can make separate `KnownSettingString` and `KnownSettingInt` classes inheriting from `KnownSetting<T>` and defining fields of appropriaye types. Then just add a container class that group the values from both.

Comment: I suppose you could also define `IKnownSetting<T>` and have a private class implement it within the container class. Probably not ideal, but maybe worth considering.

Comment: BTW: I would use 'string' instead of 'String'. Just a minor detail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a helper method in the base type that uses another type and create a known settings class. You need the Create method because the base constructor is Setting(string, object, Func). This is also why I introduce another generic variable (U):

```
public class KnownSetting : Setting<object>
{
    private KnownSetting(string key, object defaultValue, Func<string, object> converter) : base(key, defaultValue, converter) { }

    public readonly static Setting<string> Name = Create<string>("name", "Default Name", t => t);
    public readonly static Setting<int> Size = Create<int>("size", 25, t => Convert.ToInt32(t));
}

public class Setting<T>
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
    public Func<string, T> Converter { get; set; }

    protected static Setting<U> Create<U>(string key, U defaultValue, Func<string, U> converter)
    {
        return new Setting<U>(key, defaultValue, converter);
    }

    protected Setting(string key, T defaultValue, Func<string, T> converter)
    {
        Key = key;
        DefaultValue = defaultValue;
        Converter = converter;
    }
}
public static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = KnownSetting.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this help? Predefined has a private ctor, but unused. Setting here lacks the generic and private ctor wich is the core of the problem.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the problem. I changed my solution to reflect the problem; this should be the answer he's looking for.

Comment: If you have the protected Create, why not have the ctor private?

Comment: It has to do with types. The type of the ctor has Setting<T>([...]) so you cannot call the ctor of Setting<not-T> (simply because that's not your base class). In my code this is circumvented by calling Setting<T>.Create<U> - which is in the base class and can therefore call Setting<U> (which is in the same scope). You need inheritance for this to work - so you need some kind of protected ctor. Hope it makes some sense... Just try it - it won't compile :-)

Answer (score 3):

Declare the static data in a new class:

```
public class KnownSetting
{
    public readonly static KnownSetting<String> Name = new KnownSetting<String>("name", "Default Name", t => t);
    public readonly static KnownSetting<int> Size = new KnownSetting<String>("size", "25", t => Converter.ToInt32);
}
```

It can have the same name in C# because class names are unique on name plus generic type argument count.

Comment: Additionally, you can have `KnownSetting<T>` inherit from `KnownSetting`, so there's a "generic" non-typed form which you can group them together as if necessary.

Comment: But the constructor of `KnownSetting<T>` needs to public for this to work.

Comment: @usr It's close. Not perfect, but the best idea so far IMHO.

Comment: @usr As you can see in my solution it can also be protected, thereby hiding it properly. Note that you cannot use a protected ctor directly; you're correct that it has to be internal, which always leaves a nasty taste in my mouth to be honest...

Comment: @StefandeBruijn in my code I treat internal functions with care when I call them. I always ask myself: Am I supposed to call this? For public functions I always assume I can call them without violating architecture. This convention solves the problem for me.

Comment: @usr same here, which is why I rather avoid using internal unless I really, really need them. It's like friend classes in c++ - you know you are going to need them, but you'd rather not. In this case it can be avoided, so I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just use your `KnownSetting<T>` class as is, and make new references to the same enum instances from a new class? Something like:

```
public static class KnownSettings {
  public readonly static KnownSetting<string> Name = KnownSetting<string>.Name;
  public readonly static KnownSetting<int> Size = KnownSetting<int>.Size;
  // etc.
}
```

Then you can use the values as desired:

```
var x = KnownSettings.Name;
```

Comment: Because KnownSetting<T> and KnownSetting (no generics) isn't the same class, so the non-generic cannot see the private ctor or the generic one.

Comment: @Spooles: But it doesn't need to see the constructor, it only needs to see the constructed `public readonly static` field.  All `KnownSetting<T>` values can be constructed entirely internally to `KnownSetting<T>`, but clients can still access those values through another field on another class.